# Running an Alfresco Action after one week a rule is executed

Tags: alfresco

I wrote a script to run for an Alfresco rule. but I want the script to run after specific time ( I need the script to run after 1 week). any solution?

I read about [Scheduled_Actions](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Scheduled_Actions) , is this feature useful?

Comment: you can find a complete guide to cron the action here http://alch3mi5t.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/scheduled-custom-action-alfresco.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact a Scheduled Action is likely your *only* option for for running something after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

At a high level your solution should look something like:

1. Your rule sets some aspect/property on the relevant node, say ruleDate, which is the date the original rule ran.
2. A scheduled action runs every day and detects nodes with a ruleDate 7 days or more in the past.
3. The scheduled action does whatever changes are required.
4. The scheduled action removes the ruleDate aspect/property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is useful. You need to set up cron job to run scheduled task. 
You can find more details on [this link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/run-js-script-cron-scheduled-jobs-contextxml-08012014-1613).